# display light on battery ie dimming

Tags: windows-7

My Samsung netbook NP300E5A screen is continually dimming. The screen is forty percent dim on battery, but if I plug in the charger, the screen will be normal. I have tried all I know and I could not fix it. What should I do? what am trying to explain is that the system is dimming like flooricent light the screen resolution systems are all ok. When I pluging my charge the dimming we stop but when is on battery it look like flashing someone light when driving

Comment: Do not repeat post you questions. It is against SU policy.

Comment: If you have extra information then you can edit your previous question to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the windows power options. If you go to Control Panel -> Power Options, you can set the behavior of the display when on AC power or the battery. If using Windows 10, you can just type 'power options' in the start search and it should be the first entry.